# why spyscroll is affected by collapse bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5 as a CSS framework and I'm working on a large section, so I decided to have one row with four columns and hide the rest with collapse bootstrap. However, because it is a one-page website, I am using spyscroll and a fixed navigation with an active class to track which page it is. But when I click show more "collapse," the spyscroll loses its logic and begins to jumble. Is there a way to fix this? It is worth noting that if I remove the active link, the spyscroll works perfectly fine. So technically nothing wrong with bootstrap spyscroll but the active link is the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap ScrollSpy</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{
    position: relative; /* required */
}
  
/* Custom style to stick list group on top */
.list-group{
    position: sticky;
    top: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-offset="15" data-bs-target="#myScrollspy">
<div class="container-lg my-2">
    <h1>Bootstrap Scrollspy</h1>
    <p class="lead"><i>Scroll this web page and see how the list group items are highlighted automatically based on the scroll position.</i></p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" href="#section1">Section One</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#section2">Section Two</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#section3">Section Three</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#section4">Section Four</a>
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#section5">Section Five</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">I'm using bootstrap 5 as a CSS framework and I'm working on a large section, so I decided to have one row with four columns and hide the rest with collapse bootstrap. However, because it is a one-page website, I am using spyscroll and a fixed navigation with an active class to track which page it is. But when I click show more "collapse," the spyscroll loses its logic and begins to jumble. Is there a way to fix this? It is worth noting that if I remove the active link, the spyscroll works perfectly fine.      <div id="expertise" class="container more-link-btn">
         <h2>Industry Expertise</h2>
         <div class="row industry">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
               <h6>Digital <br> Security</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Innovation hub for the development of new products and
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     control, eVisa Transport solutions such as e-driver license, e-vehicle registration card, secure car plates with RFID tags, city tolls. Identification solutions such as civil and land registry, Biometric IDs (national, residency, work, health, voter, etc.)</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn1">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
               <h6>Smartcard <br> manufacturing</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Card based solutions such as banking cards, telecom
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     SIM cards, and contactless cardsolutions. Secure print solutions such as chequebooks, fiscal and postal stamps, official exam forms, transport tickets and excise tax stamps.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn2">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
               <h6>Banking <br> and payment</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Biometric payment cards, banking cards, cheque
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     books, secure documents, digital banking, eKYC, fraud detection, digital payments, virtual cards, and open banking.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn3">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
               <h6>Project deployment <br> and management</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Project execution in a suitable environment
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     , and monitoring and overseeing performance according to a tailored plan and specific timeline.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn4">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row collapse multi-collapse industry pb-1" id="multiCollapseExample1">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>R&D and Software <br> development</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Innovation hub for the development of new products and
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     services, including the creation of custom software solutions and products.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn5">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Information and <br> Communication Technology (ICT) </h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>ICT infrastructure such as Fiber optic (FTTX), secure
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     communications, mobile broadband, optical transport network, gigabit backhauling, and others.
                     Digital and smart platforms for telcos and defense including cybersecurity and tactical solutions.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn6">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Technology <br> aggregation</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Summary and compilation of reliable data for high
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     level analysis to help make better decisions, improve process efficiency, understand consumer’s behavior and contribute to business decisions and strategic planning. </span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn7">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Elections <br> solutions</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Biometric voter enrolment solution such as mobile and 
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     fixed stations and handheld devices to control voters’ identity. 
                     Elections material supply chain such as ballot boxes, polling booths, indelible ink, voting kits and secure printed forms.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn8">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Startups <br> incubation </h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>R&D labs and incubation technology hub for technology 
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     development, supporting functions, startup funding and mentoring.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn9">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Game development <br> and publishing </h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Metaverse, VR, mobile and PC. 
                     <span id="dots"></span><span id="more" >
                     </span>
                  </p>
                  <!-- <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn10">+</div> -->
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Metaverse and <br> web3 consultancy</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Digital art and assets in the Metaverse such as offices 
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     development, supporting functions, startup funding and mentoring., trainings, onboarding, game/VR development.
                     NFTs including art creation, smart contracts on blockchain, loyalty programs, community management, and strategy for digital transformation.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn11">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Renewable <br> energy</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Photovoltaic energy, wind energy, solar water heating technology 
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     and energy efficiency.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn12">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Road safety <br> education</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Driving tuition methodologies and infrastructures for 
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     cutting edge road safety education since 1991 under international driving and safety standards, and with the support of international partners such as the Institute of The Motor Industry in the UK (IMI), the International Association for Driver Education and the Institute of Advanced Motorist in the UK (IAM). 
                     Driver Training Methodology accredited by AA Driving School in the UK and awarded the certification of being an Affiliate of the AA Driving School.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn13">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Satellite imagery <br> and GIS</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Delivering comprehensive Geo Information Solutions 
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     across the entire business spectrum  since 2002.
                     Receiving station for earth observation satellite imagery through own satellite. 
                     Providing a wide range of strategic and technical approaches on Natural and Environment sciences and applications by combining Remote Sensing and GIS with earth science skilled staff.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn14">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Sports <br> management</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Managing the various business aspects in sports 
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     activities such as planning, budgeting, consulting and leading within an organization or department related to sport or physical activity.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn15">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Real <br> estate</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Providing end-to-end solutions and services that 
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     help connect people and places. A wide portfolio of residential, office, retail, industrial and mixed-use assets spread across several Emirates in the UAE.
                     Services include property management, tenancy management, sales and leasing, marketing and promotion, maintenance and renovation, and legal advice.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn16">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query-last">
               <h6>Vehicle and <br> container inspection</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Providing solutions for precise vehicles and container 
                     <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more" >
                     inspection. Working with global technical partners, such as SGS, the world’s leading inspection, verification, testing and certification company.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn17">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="py-3">
            <a class="more-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" id="link" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1"> Show more &nbsp;</a>
         </div>
      </div>
            <div id="section1">
                <h2>Section One</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus us. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>
                <p>Quis quam ut magna consequat faucibus. Pellentesque eget nisi a mi suscipit tincidunt. Ut tempus dictum risus. Pellentesque viverra sagittis quam at mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio. Phasellus auctor velit at lacus blandit, commodo iaculis justo viverra. Etiam vitae est arcu. Mauris vel congue dolor. Aliquam eget mi mi. Fusce quam tortor, commodo ac dui quis, bibendum viverra erat. Maecenas mattis lectus enim, quis tincidunt dui molestie euismod. Curabitur et diam tristique, accumsan nunc eu, hendrerit tellus.</p>
                 <p>Orci facilisis, dignissim tortor vitae, ultrices mi. Vestibulum a iaculis lacus. Phasellus vitae convalt fermentum sapien auctor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed eu elementum nibh, quis varius libero.</p>
                <p>Nam eget purus nec est consectetur vehicula. Nullam ultrices nisl risus, in viverra libero egestas sit amet. Etiam porttitor dolor non eros pulvinar malesuada. Vestibulum sit amet est mollis nulla tempus aliquet. Praesent luctus hendrerit arcu non laoreet. Morbi consequat placerat magna, ac ornare odio sagittis sed. Donec vitae ullamcorper purus. Vivamus non metus ac justo porta volutpat.</p>
                <p>Pulvinar leo id risus pellentesque vestibulum. Sed diam libero, sodales eget sapien vel, porttitor bibendum enim. Donec sed nibh vitae lorem porttitor blandit in nec ante. Pellentesque vitae metus ipsum. Phasellus sed nunc ac sem malesuada condimentum. Etiam in aliquam lectus. Nam vel sapien diam. Donec pharetra id arcu eget blandit. Proin imperdiet mattis augue in porttitor. Quisqupien at purus lacinia porttitor. Nullam iaculis, felis a pretium ornare, dolor nisl semper tortor, vel sagittis lacus est consequat eros. Sed id pretium nisl. Curabitur dolor nisl, laoreet vitae aliquam id.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div id="section2">
                <h2>Section Two</h2>
                <p>Nullam hendrerit justo non leo aliquet imperdiet. Etiam in sagittis lectus. Suspendisse ultrices placerat accumsan. Mauris quis dapibus orci. In dapibus velit blandit pharetra tincidunt. Quisque non sapien nec lacus condimentum facilisis ut iaculis enim. Sed viverra interdum bibendum. Donec ac sollicitudin dolor. Sed fringilla vitae lacus at rutrum. Phasellus congue vestibulum ligula sed consequat.</p>
                <p>Enim arc odio ac erat blandit vehicula ut eget urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam ut iaculis nibh, eget eleifend elit.</p>
                <p>Convallis eget pretium eu, bibendum non leo. Proin suscipit purus adipiscing dolor gravida, in fermentum sapien blandit. Praesent pellentesque ligula dui, in gravida turpis vehicula ac. Pellentesque hendrerit nunc ut luctus hendrerit. Aliquam nec tincidunt urna. Ut interdum nec odio non interdum. Curabitur ligula justo, dapibus non ligula tristique, dapibus tristique nulla. Aliquam pulvinar dapibus eros, rutrum pretium urna iaculis ut. Nam est est, tempus id egestas et, viverra in dui. Aliquam gravida orci tortor, sed congue justo ornare vel. Cras in quam consectetur eros varius scelerisque. Ut vel fermentum purus. Nullam interdum blandit turpis, id pellentesque massa feugiat at. Ut sed lectus lectus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla rutrum, ante quis convallis ultricies, magna quam rhoncus erat, in lacinia libero magna a ipsum.</p>
                <p>Fusce enim arcu, eget eleifend elit.</p>
                <p>Tibulum consectetur scelerisque lacus, ac fermentum lorem convallis sed. Nam odio tortor, dictum quis malesuada at, pellentesque vitae orci. Vivamus elementum, felis eu auctor lobortis, diam velit egestas lacus, quis fermentum metus ante quis urna. Sed at facilisis libero. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum bibendum blandit dolor. Nunc orci dolor, molestie nec nibh in, hendrerit tincidunt ante. Vivamus sem augue, hendrerit non sapien in, mollis ornare augue.</p>
                <p>Diam, id molestie magna. Aentum, est a faucibus luctus, mi dolor cursus mi, id vehicula arcu risus a nibh. Pellentesque blandit sapien lacus, vel vehicula nunc feugiat sit amet.</p>
                <p>Nec est consectetur vehicula. Nullam ultrices nisl risus, in viverra libero egestas sit amet. Etiam porttitor dolor non eros pulvinar malesuada. Vestibulum sit amet est mollis nulla tempus aliquet. Praesent luctus hendrerit arcu non laoreet. Morbi consequat placerat magna, ac ornare odio sagittis sed. Donec vitae ullamcorper purus. Vivamus non metus ac justo porta volutpat.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div id="section3">
                <h2>Section Three</h2>
                <p>Integer pulvinar leo id risus pellentesque vestibulum. Sed diam libero, sodales eget sapien vel, porttitor bibendum enim. Donec sed nibh vitae lorem porttitor blandit in nec ante. Pellentesque vitaeblandit. Proin imperdiet mattis augue in porttitor. Quisque tempus enim id lobortis feugiat. Suspendisse tincidunt risus quis dolor fringilla blandit. Ut sed sapien at purus lacinia porttitor. Nullam iaculis, felis a pretium ornare, dolor nisl semper tortor, vel sagittis lacus est consequat eros. Sed id pretium nisl. Curabitur dolor nisl, laoreet vitae aliquam id, tincidunt sit amet mauris.</p>
                <p>Phasellus vitae suscipit justo. Mauris pharetra feugiat ante id lacinia. Etiam faucibus mauris id tempor egestas. Dui nisi, id vulputate ipsum ullamcorper ut. Cras ac pulvinar purus, ac viverra est. Suspendisse potenti. Integer pellentesque neque et elementum tempus. Curabitur bibendum in ligula ut rhoncus.</p>
                <p>Quisque pharetra velit id velit iaculis pretium. Nullam a justo sed ligula porta semper eu quis enim. Pellentesque pellentesque, metus at facilisis hendrerit, lectus velit facilisis leo, quis volutpat turpis arcu quis enim. Nulla viverra lorem elementum interdum ultricies. Suspendisse accumsan quam nec ante mollis tempus. Morbi vel accumsan diam, eget convallis tellus. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
                <p>Integer pulvinar leo id risus pellentesque vestibulum. Sed diam libero, sodales eget sapien vel, porttitor bibendum enim. Donec sed nibh vitae lorem porttitor blandit in nec ante. Pellentesque vitae metus ipsum. Phasellus sed nunc ac sem malesuada condimentum. Etiam in aliquam lectus. Nam vel sarttitor. Nullam iaculis, felis a pretium ornare, dolor nisl semper tortor, vel sagittis lacus est consequat eros. Sed id pretium nisl. Curabitur dolor nisl, laoreet vitae aliquam id.</p>
                <p>Phasellus vitae suscipit justo. Mauris pharetra feugiat ante id lacinia. Etiam faucibus mauris id tempor egestas. Duis luctus turpis at accumsan tincidunt. Phasellus risus risus, volutpat vel  elit nisi, id vulputate ipsum ullamcorper ut. Cras ac pulvinar purus, ac viverra est. Suspendisse potenti. Integer pellentesque neque et elementum tempus. Curabitur bibendum in ligula ut rhoncus.</p>
                <p>Disque pharetra velit id velit iaculis pretium. Nullam a justo sed ligula porta semper eu quis enim. Nulla viverra lorem elementum interdum ultricies. Suspendisse accumsan quam nec ante mollis tempus. Morbi vel accumsan diam, eget convallis tellus. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div id="section4">
                <h2>Section Four</h2>
                <p>Suspendisse a orci facilisis, dignissim tortor vitae, ultrices mi. Vestibulum a iaculis lacus. Phasellus vitae convallis ligula, nec volutpat tellus. Vivamus scelerisque mollis nec dui convallis, sit amet fermentum sapien auctor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed eu elementum nibh, quis varius libero.</p>
                <p>Vestibulum quis quam ut magna consequat faucibus. Pellentesque eget nisi a mi suscipit tincidunt. Ut tempus dictum risus. Pellentesque viverra sagittis quam at mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio. Phasellus auctor velit at lacus blandit, commodo iaculis justo viverra. Etiam vitae est arcu. Mauris vel congue dolor. Aliquam eget mi mi. Fusce quam tortor, commodo ac dui quis, bibendum viverra erat. Maecenas mattis lectus enim, quis tincidunt dui molestie euismod. Curabitur et diam tristique, accumsan nunc eu, hendrerit tellus.</p>
                <p>Phasel ut dapibus luctus, massa enim elementum purus, sit amet tristique purus purus nec felis. Morbi vestibulum sapien eget porta pulvinar. Nam at quam diam. Proin rhoncus, felis elemenam sed sodales aliquam, lorem libero hendrerit urna, faucibus rhoncus massa nibh at felis. Curabitur ac tempus nulla, ut semper erat. Vivamus porta ullamcorper sem, ornare egestas mauris facilisis id.</p>
                <p>Ut ut risus nisl. Fusce porttitor eros at magna luctus, non congue nulla eleifend. Aenean porttitor feuulis. Quisque eget commodo ligula. Praesent leo dui, facilisis quis eleifend in, aliquet vitae nunc. Suspendisse fermentum odio ac massa ultricies pellentesque. Fusce eu suscipit massa.</p>
                <p>In mauris nunc, convallis eget pretium eu, bibendum non leo. Proin suscipit purus adipiscing dolor gravida, inque hendrerit nunc ut luctus hendrerit. Aliquam nec tincidunt urna. Ut interdum nec odio non interdum. Curabitur ligula justo, dapibus non ligula tristique, dapib
                <p>Bvtae lobortis diam, id molestie magna. Aliquam consequat ipsum quis est dictum ultrices. Aenean nibh velit, fringilla in diam id, blandit hendrerit lacus. Donec vehicula rutrum tellus eget fermentum. Pellentesque ac erat et arcu ornare tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus lobortis urna quis a nibh. Pellentesque blandit sapien lacus, vel vehicula nunc feugiat sit amet.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div id="section5">
                <h2>Section Five</h2>
                <p>Nam eget purus nec est consectetur vehicula. Nullam ultrices nisl risus, in viverra libero egestas sit amet. Etiam porttitor dolor non eros pulvinar malesuada. Vestibulum sit amet est mollis nulla tempus aliqused. Donec vitae ullamcorper purus. Vivamus non metus ac justo porta volutpat.</p>
                <p>Vivamus mattis accumsan erat, vel convallis risus pretium nec. Integer nunc nulla, viverra ut sem non, scelerisque vehicula arcu. Fusce bibendum convallis augue sit amet lobortis. Cras porta urna turpis, sodales lobortis purus adipiscing id. Maecenas ullamcorper, turpis suscipit pellentesque fringilla, massa lacus pulvinar mi, nec dignissim velit arcu eget purus. Nam at dapibus tellus, eget euismod nisl. Ut eget venenatis sapien. Vivamus vulputate varius mauris, vel varius nisl facilisis ac. Nulla aliquet justo a nibh ornare, eu congue neque rutrum.</p>
                <p>Suspendisse a orci facilisis, dignissim tortor vitae, ultrices mi. Vestibulum a iaculis lacus. Phasellus vitae convallis ligula, nec volutpat tellus. Vivamus scelerisque mollis nisl, nec vehicula elit egestas a. Sed luctus metus id mi gravida, faucibus convallis neque pretium. Maecenas qulus sodales libero nec dui convallis, sit amet fermentum sapien auctor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed eu elementum nibh, quis varius libero.</p>
                <p>Morbi sed fermentum ipsum. Morbi a orci vulputate tortor ornare blandit a quis orci. Donec aliquam sodales gravida. In ut ullamcorper nisi, ac pretium velit. Vestibulum vitae lectus volutpat, consequat lorem sit amet, pulvinar tellus. In tincidunt vel leo eget pulvinar. Curabitur a eros non lacus malesuada aliquam. Praesent et tempus odio. Integer a quam nunc. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam porta nibh nulla, et mattis turpis placerat eget. Pellentesque dui diam, pellentesque vel gravida id, accumsan eu magna. Sed a semper arcu, ut dignissim leo.</p>
                <p>Sed vitae lobortis diam, id molestie magna. Aliquam consequat ipsum quis est dictum ultrices. Aenean gravida semper. In condimentum, est a faucibus luctus, mi dolor cursus mi, id vehicula arcu risus a nibh. Pellentesque blandit sapien lacus, vel vehicula nunc feugiat sit amet.</p>
                <p>Gonvallis eget pretium eu, bibendum non leo. Proin suscipit purus adipiscing dolor gravida, in fermentum sapien blandit. Praesent pellentesque ligula dui, in gravida turpis vehicula ac.  Nam est est, tempus id egestas et, viverra in duis convallis ultricies, magna quam rhoncus erat, in lacinia libero magna a ipsum.</p>
                <p>Eget purus nec est consectetur vehicula. Nullam ultrices nisl risus, in viverra libero egestas sit amet. Donec vitae ullamcorper purus. Vivamus non metus ac justo porta volutpat.</p>
                <p>Etiam porttitor dolor non eros pulvinar malesuada. Vestibulum sit amet est mollis nulla tempus aliquet. Praesent luctus hendrerit arcu non laoreet. Morbi consequat placerat magna, ac ornare odio sagittis sed. Donec vitae ullamcorper purus. Vivamus non metus ac justo porta volutpat. ac justo porta volutpat.</p>
              
                <p>Suspendisse a orci facilisis, dignissim tortor vitae, ultrices mi. Vestibulum a iaculis lacus. </p>
                <p>Fermentum ipsum. Morbi a orci vulputate tortor ornare blandit a quis orci. Donec aliquam sodales gravida. In ut ullamcorper nisi, ac pretium velit. Vestibulum vitae lectus volutpat, consequat lorem sit amet, pulvinar tellus. In tincidunt vel leo eget pulvinar. Curabitur a eros non lacus malesuada a</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using bootstrap's spyscroll, use jQuery sticky navigation with smooth scroll functionality for your single page web application.
so i took this demo from [this site](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Sticky-Navigation-Smooth-Scroll-Scrollspy/)  as an example, and I added your show more / show less section so you can feel the difference; if you test it, you will see that there is no problem even if the section is fully expanded; the active class will track the sections flawlessly.

```js
/*!============================================================
 * jquery.sticky-nav.js
 * Copyright (c) Federico Cargnelutti <fedecarg@gmail.com>
 * http://www.fedecarg.com/
 ============================================================*/

(function($) {

  $.fn.stickynav = function(options) {

    const DEFAULT_SELECTORS = {
      navActiveClass:    'active',   // Selected nav item modifier class
      navStickyClass:    'sticky',   // Sticky nav modifier class
      sectionSelector:   'section'   // Section id, class or tag selector
    };

    // Merge options with defaults
    options = $.extend({}, DEFAULT_SELECTORS, options);

    // Set jQuery DOM elements
    const $nav = this;
    const $navLinks = $nav.find('a');
    const $sections = $(options.sectionSelector);

    const navHeight = $nav.height();
    const scrollTopOffset = $sections.first().height() / 2;

    let currentScrollPosition = 0;
    let offsetNumbers = [0];


    function initialise() {
      calculateOffsets();
      bindEvents();
    }

    function bindEvents() {
      $navLinks.on('click', onClick);
      $(window).on('scroll', throttle(onScroll, 20));
    }

    function onClick(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const targetEl = $(this).attr('href');

      if ($(targetEl).length) {
        selectNavItem(this);

          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(targetEl).offset().top - navHeight
          });
        }
    }

    function onScroll() {
      var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop() + navHeight,
          closestPosition = findClosestNumber(scrollTop, offsetNumbers);

      // select navbar item
      if (closestPosition !== currentScrollPosition) {
        selectNavItem('.section-offset-' + closestPosition);
        currentScrollPosition = closestPosition;
      }

      // fix navbar
      if (scrollTop > scrollTopOffset) {
        $nav.addClass(options.navStickyClass);
      } else {
        $nav.removeClass(options.navStickyClass);
      }
    }

    function findClosestNumber(num, arr) {
      return arr.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        return (Math.abs(curr - num) < Math.abs(prev - num) ? curr : prev);
      });
    }

    function calculateOffsets() {
      $sections.each(function(index) {
        const el = $(this)[0];
        const offsetTop = getOffsetTop(el);

        offsetNumbers.push(offsetTop);
        getNavItem(el).addClass('section-offset-' + offsetTop);
      });
    }

    function getOffsetTop(el) {
        const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
              scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        return Math.round(rect.top + scrollTop);
    }

    function getNavItem(el) {
      return $('nav a[href="#' + $(el).attr('id') + '"]');
    }

    function selectNavItem(el) {
      if (!$nav.hasClass(options.navStickyClass)) {
        $nav.addClass(options.navStickyClass);
      }

      $navLinks.removeClass(options.navActiveClass);
      $(el).addClass(options.navActiveClass);
    }

    function throttle(func, delay) {
      let timer = 0;

      return function() {
        const context = this,
        args = [].slice.call(arguments);

        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
          func.apply(context, args);
        }, delay);
      };
    }

    initialise();
  };

}(jQuery))
;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav').stickynav();

  $('.navbar-toggler').click(() => {
    $('.navbar-collapse').toggleClass('show');
  });
});

$('.nav-link').on('click',function() {
  $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});

/* + & - */ 
function myFunction(btn_id) {
  
  var btnText = document.getElementById(btn_id.id);
  var parentElem = btn_id.parentElement;
  var childElemP = parentElem.childNodes;
  var spanElem = childElemP[1].childNodes;
  
  if (spanElem[1].style.display === "none") {
    spanElem[1].style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "+"; 
    spanElem[2].style.display = "none";
  } else {
    spanElem[1].style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "-"; 
    spanElem[2].style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
header {
  padding: 150px 0 100px;
}

section {
  min-height: 600px;
  padding: 50px 0 50px;
}

.navbar .nav-link {
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.navbar .nav-link.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Sticky navigation bar with content section highlight">
    <meta name="author" content="Federico Cargnelutti">

    <title>jQuery StickyNav - By Federico Cargnelutti @fedecarg</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#header">StickyNav Demo</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#download">Download</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <header class="bg-primary text-white" id="header">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>jQuery StickyNav</h1>
        <p class="lead">Sticky navigation bar with content section highlight</p>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section id="features">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <h2>Features</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Clickable nav links that smooth scroll to content sections</li>
              <li>Responsive behavior when clicking nav links perfect for single page applications</li>
              <li>Highlights which section of the page you're on in the navigation bar</li>
              <li>Minimal custom CSS so you are free to explore your own unique design options</li>
              <li>Uses a variant of the Binary Search Algorithm to determine the position of an element before binding an event handler to the scroll event.</li>
              <li>Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the onScroll() event handler when scrolling. It only calls the event handler function once per every given number of milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events like scroll and resize.</li>
              <li>No need to include bootstrap.bundle.min.js, jquery.waypoints.min.js or any other bloated js library</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="download" class="bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <h2>Download</h2>
            <p class="lead">Compressed and uncompressed copies of jQuery StickyNav files are available. The uncompressed file is best used during development or debugging; the compressed file saves bandwidth and improves performance in production.</p>
            <p><a href="https://github.com/fedecarg/sticky-nav/tree/master/dist">https://github.com/fedecarg/sticky-nav/tree/master/dist</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="about">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Industry Expertise</h2>
         <div class="row industry">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
               <h6>Digital <br> Security</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Innovation hub for the development of new products and
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     control, eVisa Transport solutions such as e-driver license, e-vehicle registration card, secure car plates with RFID tags, city tolls. Identification solutions such as civil and land registry, Biometric IDs (national, residency, work, health, voter, etc.)</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn1">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
               <h6>Smartcard <br> manufacturing</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Card based solutions such as banking cards, telecom
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     SIM cards, and contactless cardsolutions. Secure print solutions such as chequebooks, fiscal and postal stamps, official exam forms, transport tickets and excise tax stamps.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn2">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
               <h6>Banking <br> and payment</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Biometric payment cards, banking cards, cheque
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     books, secure documents, digital banking, eKYC, fraud detection, digital payments, virtual cards, and open banking.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn3">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
               <h6>Project deployment <br> and management</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Project execution in a suitable environment
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     , and monitoring and overseeing performance according to a tailored plan and specific timeline.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn4">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row collapse multi-collapse industry pb-1" id="multiCollapseExample1">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>R&D and Software <br> development</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Innovation hub for the development of new products and
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     services, including the creation of custom software solutions and products.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn5">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Information and <br> Communication Technology (ICT) </h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>ICT infrastructure such as Fiber optic (FTTX), secure
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     communications, mobile broadband, optical transport network, gigabit backhauling, and others.
                     Digital and smart platforms for telcos and defense including cybersecurity and tactical solutions.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn6">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Technology <br> aggregation</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Summary and compilation of reliable data for high
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     level analysis to help make better decisions, improve process efficiency, understand consumer’s behavior and contribute to business decisions and strategic planning. </span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn7">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Elections <br> solutions</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Biometric voter enrolment solution such as mobile and 
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     fixed stations and handheld devices to control voters’ identity. 
                     Elections material supply chain such as ballot boxes, polling booths, indelible ink, voting kits and secure printed forms.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn8">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Startups <br> incubation </h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>R&D labs and incubation technology hub for technology 
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     development, supporting functions, startup funding and mentoring.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn9">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Game development <br> and publishing </h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Metaverse, VR, mobile and PC. 
                     <span class="dots"></span><span class="more" >
                     </span>
                  </p>
                  <!-- <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn10">+</div> -->
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Metaverse and <br> web3 consultancy</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Digital art and assets in the Metaverse such as offices 
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     development, supporting functions, startup funding and mentoring., trainings, onboarding, game/VR development.
                     NFTs including art creation, smart contracts on blockchain, loyalty programs, community management, and strategy for digital transformation.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn11">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Renewable <br> energy</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Photovoltaic energy, wind energy, solar water heating technology 
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     and energy efficiency.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn12">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Road safety <br> education</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Driving tuition methodologies and infrastructures for 
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     cutting edge road safety education since 1991 under international driving and safety standards, and with the support of international partners such as the Institute of The Motor Industry in the UK (IMI), the International Association for Driver Education and the Institute of Advanced Motorist in the UK (IAM). 
                     Driver Training Methodology accredited by AA Driving School in the UK and awarded the certification of being an Affiliate of the AA Driving School.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn13">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Satellite imagery <br> and GIS</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Delivering comprehensive Geo Information Solutions 
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     across the entire business spectrum  since 2002.
                     Receiving station for earth observation satellite imagery through own satellite. 
                     Providing a wide range of strategic and technical approaches on Natural and Environment sciences and applications by combining Remote Sensing and GIS with earth science skilled staff.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn14">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Sports <br> management</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Managing the various business aspects in sports 
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     activities such as planning, budgeting, consulting and leading within an organization or department related to sport or physical activity.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn15">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query">
               <h6>Real <br> estate</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Providing end-to-end solutions and services that 
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     help connect people and places. A wide portfolio of residential, office, retail, industrial and mixed-use assets spread across several Emirates in the UAE.
                     Services include property management, tenancy management, sales and leasing, marketing and promotion, maintenance and renovation, and legal advice.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn16">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 p-query-last">
               <h6>Vehicle and <br> container inspection</h6>
               <div class="card-body">
                  <p>Providing solutions for precise vehicles and container 
                     <span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" >
                     inspection. Working with global technical partners, such as SGS, the world’s leading inspection, verification, testing and certification company.</span>
                  </p>
                  <div class="plusminus" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="myBtn17">+</div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="py-3">
            <a class="more-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" id="link" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1"> Show more &nbsp;</a>
         </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="contact" class="bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <h2>Contact us</h2>
            <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero odio fugiat voluptatem dolor, provident officiis, id iusto! Obcaecati incidunt, qui nihil beatae magnam et repudiandae ipsa exercitationem, in, quo totam.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Federico Cargnelutti</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- (1) Include jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>    <script src="js/vendor/babel-polyfill-6.26.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- (2) Include StickyNav -->
    <script src="js/jquery.sticky-nav.js"></script>
    <script>
      // (3) Instantiate StickyNav
     
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```